# Why is $C^{-\infty}$ useful?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

So, $C^{-\infty}(\Omega) := (C_c^{\infty}(\Omega))'$, that is the space of 
all continuous linear functionals over the space of compactly supported smooth functions. $C^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is larger than tempered distributions $S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and we would get elements of $C^{-\infty}$ that aren't in 
$S'$ if we took for example the integral pairing, $ u \Psi \to \int \phi \Psi$ for some $\phi \in C^{\infty}$.

My question is what is the motivation behind these very general distributions? Are there examples where being in tempered distributions is not general enough? We have for example that Fourier transform is an isomorphism on $S'$ which is pretty useful but we don't have nice properties (I should say that
I don't know any) on the very general $C^{-\infty}$, so I am wondering where 
they are needed. Thank you!

Comment: The most commonly used reason in my experience: it's pedagogically easier to introduce $C_c^{\infty}$ than $S$.

Comment: I've never seen the notation $C^{-\infty}$. Normally the space of distributions is denoted by $\mathcal D'$.

Comment: $\mathscr D' (\Omega) $ has a meaning for every open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from observation but not experience, it seems people mainly consider tempered distributions in settings that make extensive use of Fourier analysis.

Linear functionals on $C_c(\Omega)$ called [Radon measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure). Off hand, I can think of two reasons why one might like to consider them:

- People like to study compactly supported functions
- Every continuous function gives a radon measure.

Generalizing further to linear functionals on $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, I presume, is something you'd do when you're interested in derivatives.

Comment: A bit of an inaccuracy: the collection of distributions includes many things that are not Radon measures. E.g., all derivatives of Radon measures. And other things that are not so-obtainable. E.g., $\sum_n \delta^{(n)}_n$, that is the sum of $n$th derivatives of Dirac deltas at non-negative integers $n$. This is not of finite order, so is not any sort of derivative of a classical function or measure.